# how to get a true 16-bit value?

Tags: c++, types

So I'm using an LPC1768 using the mbed interface.

This snippet:

```
int16_t test = -1;
test -= 1;
printf("Value: %d\n", sizeof(test));
if (test== 0xFFFE) {
    printf("It's stayed the same.\n");
} else if (test== 0xFFFFFFFE) {
    printf("It's been extended.\n");
} else {
    printf("None\n");
}
```

prints out
Value: 2
It's been extended.

How could I modify this so that it will print "It's stayed the same."? The goal is to have

```
int16_t test = -1
```

make test be a 16 bit value with all bits set.

Comment: C or C++? Pick one.

Comment: Are you compiling with warnings? I get this on the expression `test == 0xFFFE`: `warning: comparison of constant 65534 with expression of type 'int16_t' (aka 'short') is always false`

Comment: If C++ then why are you using `printf()` instead of `std::cout`?

Comment: @cdhowie: If memory serves, isn't C++ (more or less) a superset of C?  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm... genuinely not sure whether or not you're being sarcastic.

Comment: Well, it will either compile under C++ or it won't.  Sure looks like C code to me, though.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Sure. But the answer depends on whether we have `static_cast` (C++) or must resort to a C-style cast (which are discouraged in C++ due to their proclivity to do things unintended by the programmer).

Comment: @RobertHarvey: C is **not** a subset of C++! As a mod **please** don't spread this wrong statement. Try `static const int i = 10; static int a[i];` in both languages. (hint the syntax is valid in both languages).

Comment: @Olaf: Moderation doesn't have anything to do with this.  And your example *suggests compatibility, not incompatibility.*  Don't take your eye off the ball.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Did you try it in both languages? Hint: it only works in one of them, **despite** the syntax being valid in both languages. That was my point.

Answer (score 2):

`0xFFFFFFFE` and `0xFFFE` are both `int` constants. The former is out of range of `int` so it overflows into the negative (-2), then the `short` operand is widened to `int` (with sign extension) and the comparison succeeds.  The latter is equivalent to the value 65534, which is not equal to -2.

To make the test succeed, cast the literal `0xFFFE` to `int16_t`, which will cause it to overflow to the value -2:

```
if (test == static_cast<int16_t>(0xFFFE)) {
```